# Assembler - loop with ECX

Tags: assembly, x86

as we know, the `loop X` instruction is going over `X` until `ECX = 0`.

My question - What the loop instruction do first: decrement the ECX, or check if ECX == 0.

Meaning, what of the below is corect

*first*

```
   ECX = ECX - 1;
   if ECX > 0
       go to X
```

*second*

```
   if ECX > 0 {
       ECX = ECX - 1;
       fo to x; }
```

Thanks.

Comment: The first. Protip: don't use `loop`, it's slow.

Comment: @harold sounds like an answer to me.

Comment: [Q&A about why `loop` is slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35742570/why-is-the-loop-instruction-slow-couldnt-intel-have-implemented-it-efficiently)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first. From Intel's manual 2A:

> Each time the LOOP instruction is executed, the count register is decremented, then
>   checked for 0. If the count is 0, the loop is terminated and program execution
>   continues with the instruction following the LOOP instruction. If the count is not zero,
>   a near jump is performed to the destination (target) operand, which is presumably
>   the instruction at the beginning of the loop.